# making a hash.to_file method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following method...

```
class output 
  # Converts a hash into a file file.
  def to_file(hash, output)
    output_file = File.new(output, 'w')
    hash.each do |id, seq|
      output_file.puts id
      output_file.puts sequence
    end
    output_file.close
  end
end
```

So when I need to write the contents of a hash into a file, so I would write the following:

```
to_output = output.new 
to_output.to_file(hash_name, output_file_name)
```

This is what I would like to do...

```
hash_name.to_file(output_file_name)
```

Is this possible and would this be better since I wouldn't need instantiate the 'output' class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `Hash#to_file`:

```
class Hash 
  def to_file(output)
    output_file = File.new(output, 'w')
    each do |id, seq|
      output_file.puts id
      output_file.puts seq
    end
    output_file.close
  end
end
```

Changes:

- `class output` => `class Hash`
- The parameter `hash` is gone.
- `hash.each` became `each` (or `self.each`)
- Fixed a typo: `sequence` => `seq`

Comment: So how would I access it... would I access it by writing `hash_name.to_file(output_file)` .... This is what I am doing and it is giving me a no method error (undefined method 'to_file')...

Comment: @IsmailM, If `hash_name` is a hash object, it should work. Try something like: `h = {'name': 'M.'}; h.to_file('test.txt')`

Comment: This is the full error - `undefined method 'to_file' for #<Hash:0x00000001b48178> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @IsmailM, Did you define `Hash#to_file` as the code in the answer?

Comment: @IsmailM, See [this screencast](http://asciinema.org/a/7464) I have just recorded.